# Template function for applying args to function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, perfect-forwarding

I trying to write a function (call it `apply_args()`) that takes a specific function or function object and arguments for calling this object, and calls it using the perfect forwarding.

Example:

```
auto fun = [](std::string a, std::string const& b) { return a += b; };

std::string s("world!");

// s is passing by lvalue ref,
// temporary object by rvalue ref 
s = apply_args(fun, std::string("Hello, "), s);
```

How can I implement that function?

Comment: Are you trying to write this because you want to learn from writing it, or are you trying to write it because you want to have it? If it’s the second one, you should probably use [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) instead.

Comment: @DanielH - `std::invoke` is a good choice but is C++17; this question is tagged C++11

Comment: @DanielH the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
decltype(auto) apply_args(Func &&f, Args &&...args) {
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: good for C++14; but the question is tagged C++11; so `auto apply_args (Func && f, Args && ... args) -> decltype( f(std::forward<Args>(args)...) )`

Answer (score 0):

If you accept to pass the `fun` lambda as `+fun` (transforming it in a function pointer), I suppose you can simply write `apply_args()` as

```
template <typename R, typename ... Fts, typename ... As>
R apply_args (R(*fn)(Fts...), As && ... as)
 { return fn(std::forward<As>(as)...); }
```

The full example

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename R, typename ... Fts, typename ... As>
R apply_args (R(*fn)(Fts...), As && ... as)
 { return fn(std::forward<As>(as)...); }

int main ()
 {
   auto fun = [](std::string a, std::string const& b) { return a += b; };

   std::string s("world!");

   s = apply_args(+fun, std::string("Hello, "), s);

   std::cout << s << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: If you use trailing return type and `decltype`, then you don’t need to specify the type of the first parameter and can just make it a template parameter `F`, and don’t need to do anything special with lambdas (and can work with things which can’t be converted to function pointers, like objects with `operator()` or lambdas with captures).

Comment: @DanielH - works; good solution (better than mine) but really different. You should propose it as an alternative answer.